# Can't make vue-slick-carousel work from CDN

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use it in a very small app using the CDN script:

https://unpkg.com/vue-slick-carousel

with no success.

I'm new to vue.js and I'n not sure if I have to import it or anything.
The documentation says I have to import it: [Vue-slick-carousel](https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-slick-carousel-with-true-ssr-written-for-faster-luxstay/)

IT should be like this but I can't make it work:

```
  import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel'
  // optional style for arrows & dots
  import 'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel-theme.css'

  export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    components: { VueSlickCarousel },
  }
```

The test is in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/oterox/pen/rNxboqo)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can't 'import' from a CDN script in the way you've done. You can access the window variable and assign it to the component. By using a CDN, it becomes bound to the window.

So `components: { VueSlickCarousel : window['vue-slick-carousel'] }` without the `import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel'` would solve that portion of your question.

The issue is that, the code referenced in the example is for packaged installs, and not a CDN. If you can install via `npm install vue-slick-carousel`, or `yarn add vue-slick-carousel`, then these problems would resolve themselves.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, the component should be kebab-case in your HTML. `<vue-slick-carousel> ... </vue-slick-carousel>` instead of `<VueSlickCarousel> ... </VueSlickCarousel>`

This is in line with the style guide provided in the Vue docs [seen here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended)

> In most projects, component names should always be PascalCase in single-file components and string templates - but kebab-case in DOM templates.

Comment: Sorry, bad link to codepen, the code is here: https://codepen.io/oterox/pen/rNxboqo
It doesn't work adding it like you said or probably I'm doing something wrong as I'n new to vue ;)

Comment: No proble, I failed to mention that the implementation of the component is kebab cased. So, if you change your `<VueSlickCarousel>` html to `<vue-slick-carousel>`, it'll work as intended.

Here's a codepen for clarity: https://codepen.io/brayden-merrifield/pen/XWXLMZE

Comment: Well, it works, but settings doesn't, "slidesToShow" don't work(or any other: https://codepen.io/oterox/pen/rNxboqo

Comment: Hello, I noticed one small problem, I tried to set the "slidesToShow" property, which does not work either.