# Slick carousel add item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, carousel, slick.js

I'm trying to add items to a Slick carousel in a vue.js demo.
If I try to `refresh()` after adding the item it doesn't work. The item is added with vue.js

```js
//This doesn't work:
jQuery('.slick').slick('refresh');
```

To make it work I have to "unslick" the carousel and then create it again which looks very bad.

```js
//Reset the slick. Works but looks UGLY
jQuery('.slick').slick('unslick');
this.setSlider();
```

You can see it in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/oterox/pen/WNrBpKE?editors=1011)

Is it possible to refresh the slick carousel when I add a new item from Vue? (without the current ugly effect)

Comment: Probably the best way would be to use the vue version of slick, vue-slick-carousel, but i can't make it work. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63086162/cant-make-vue-slick-carousel-work-from-cdn

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)? It seems to have a relatively simple way to add items to the carousel. `.slick('slickAdd',<Element here>)`

Comment: Yes, I did it. I'm new to vue but I couldn't make it work. Also I'm using vue to add it, so it should work with vue.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended that never use jquery and vue.js with each other in one project!
But if you want to use both of them ! read this article to solve some imporatant problems:

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

If you can remove jquery from your project, you can use this package to add carousel to your vue project without jquery:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-carousel

Comment: It would be great to remove jquery, but I couldn't make work any vue carousel. Couldn't add arrows to vue-carousel

Answer (score 0):

It may work four you

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    components: { 
    VueSlickCarousel : window['vue-slick-carousel'] 
    },
    data:{
      slickOptions: {
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
  },
  methods: {

  }
 })
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  user-select:none;
}

#app {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}


.slide {

  &-1, &-2, &-3, &-4 {
    height: 150px;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
     p {
       margin-top: 0;
     }
  }
  
  &-1 {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  
  &-2 {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  &-3 {
    background-color: teal;
  }
  
  &-4 {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-slick-carousel@1.0.6/dist/vue-slick-carousel.umd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <vue-slick-carousel :autoplay="true" :dots="true" :options="slickOptions">
    <div class="slide-1">
      <p>Slide 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-2">
      <p>Slide 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-3">
      <p>Slide 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-4">
      <p>Slide 4</p>
    </div>
  </vue-slick-carousel>
</div>
```

: